# "ionic cordova run android" stuck

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Executing `ionic cordova run android` command in `cli` stuck at

```
  D:\astrodasha>ionic cordova run android --verbose
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', tty: true, windows: true } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'run', 'android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, project: null, '--': [] } +8ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: @ionic/angular (angular) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: 'D:\\astrodasha\\ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'angular' } +1ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: 'C:\\Users\\yashr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'C:\\Users\\yashr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic', execPath: 'D:\\astrodasha', version: '5.4.16' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'D:\\astrodasha\\config.xml', package.json: 'D:\\astrodasha\\package.json') +0ms
  ionic:commands:run Native platform devices: [] +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'D:\\astrodasha\\config.xml', package.json: 'D:\\astrodasha\\package.json') +8s
  ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova run' [ 'android', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
  ionic:lib:build build options: {
  ionic:lib:build   '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: 'android',
  ionic:lib:build   project: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
  ionic:lib:build   configuration: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   sourcemaps: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   cordovaAssets: true,
  ionic:lib:build   watch: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'angular'
  ionic:lib:build } +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +15ms
> ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
  ng:analytics getGlobalAnalytics +0ms
  ng:analytics Client Analytics config found: false +67ms
  ng:analytics Analytics disabled. Ignoring all analytics. +3ms
  ng:analytics getSharedAnalytics +1ms
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 296 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 802 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {0} 0-es2015.js, 0-es2015.js.map () 13.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} 0-es5.js, 0-es5.js.map () 14.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1-es2015.js, 1-es2015.js.map () 20 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1-es5.js, 1-es5.js.map () 20.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2-es2015.js, 2-es2015.js.map () 17 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2-es5.js, 2-es5.js.map () 17.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4-es2015.js, 4-es2015.js.map () 31.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4-es5.js, 4-es5.js.map () 32.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3-es2015.js, 3-es2015.js.map () 31.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3-es5.js, 3-es5.js.map () 32.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es2015.js, 6-es2015.js.map () 56.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6-es5.js, 6-es5.js.map () 57.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es2015.js, 7-es2015.js.map () 4.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} 7-es5.js, 7-es5.js.map () 4.95 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es2015.js, 9-es2015.js.map () 9.43 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9-es5.js, 9-es5.js.map () 9.99 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5-es2015.js, 5-es2015.js.map () 57.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5-es5.js, 5-es5.js.map () 58.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es2015.js, 10-es2015.js.map () 9.98 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} 10-es5.js, 10-es5.js.map () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es2015.js, 8-es2015.js.map () 4.65 kB  [rendered]
chunk {8} 8-es5.js, 8-es5.js.map () 5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} 13-es2015.js, 13-es2015.js.map () 22.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} 13-es5.js, 13-es5.js.map () 23.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es2015.js, 11-es2015.js.map () 3.71 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11-es5.js, 11-es5.js.map () 3.93 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} 12-es2015.js, 12-es2015.js.map () 3.71 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} 12-es5.js, 12-es5.js.map () 3.93 kB  [rendered]
chunk {16} 16-es2015.js, 16-es2015.js.map () 11.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {16} 16-es5.js, 16-es5.js.map () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {19} 19-es2015.js, 19-es2015.js.map () 5.62 kB  [rendered]
chunk {19} 19-es5.js, 19-es5.js.map () 5.85 kB  [rendered]
chunk {15} 15-es2015.js, 15-es2015.js.map () 12 kB  [rendered]
chunk {15} 15-es5.js, 15-es5.js.map () 12.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14-es2015.js, 14-es2015.js.map () 22.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14-es5.js, 14-es5.js.map () 23.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {17} 17-es2015.js, 17-es2015.js.map () 8.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {17} 17-es5.js, 17-es5.js.map () 8.99 kB  [rendered]
chunk {18} 18-es2015.js, 18-es2015.js.map () 8.52 kB  [rendered]
chunk {18} 18-es5.js, 18-es5.js.map () 9.11 kB  [rendered]
chunk {20} 20-es2015.js, 20-es2015.js.map () 5.61 kB  [rendered]
chunk {20} 20-es5.js, 20-es5.js.map () 5.85 kB  [rendered]
chunk {23} 23-es2015.js, 23-es2015.js.map () 65.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {23} 23-es5.js, 23-es5.js.map () 65.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {21} 21-es2015.js, 21-es2015.js.map () 15.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {21} 21-es5.js, 21-es5.js.map () 16.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {29} 29-es2015.js, 29-es2015.js.map () 14.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {29} 29-es5.js, 29-es5.js.map () 15.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {24} 24-es2015.js, 24-es2015.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {24} 24-es5.js, 24-es5.js.map () 19.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {25} 25-es2015.js, 25-es2015.js.map () 18.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {25} 25-es5.js, 25-es5.js.map () 18.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {26} 26-es2015.js, 26-es2015.js.map () 3.43 kB  [rendered]
chunk {26} 26-es5.js, 26-es5.js.map () 3.66 kB  [rendered]
chunk {27} 27-es2015.js, 27-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {27} 27-es5.js, 27-es5.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {22} 22-es2015.js, 22-es2015.js.map () 66.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {22} 22-es5.js, 22-es5.js.map () 65.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {28} 28-es2015.js, 28-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {28} 28-es5.js, 28-es5.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {31} 31-es2015.js, 31-es2015.js.map () 25.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {31} 31-es5.js, 31-es5.js.map () 26.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {33} 33-es2015.js, 33-es2015.js.map () 39.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {33} 33-es5.js, 33-es5.js.map () 40.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {34} 34-es2015.js, 34-es2015.js.map () 42.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {34} 34-es5.js, 34-es5.js.map () 44.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {32} 32-es2015.js, 32-es2015.js.map () 25.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {32} 32-es5.js, 32-es5.js.map () 26.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {38} 38-es2015.js, 38-es2015.js.map () 32.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {38} 38-es5.js, 38-es5.js.map () 33.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {35} 35-es2015.js, 35-es2015.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {35} 35-es5.js, 35-es5.js.map () 13.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {37} 37-es2015.js, 37-es2015.js.map () 32 kB  [rendered]
chunk {37} 37-es5.js, 37-es5.js.map () 33 kB  [rendered]
chunk {30} 30-es2015.js, 30-es2015.js.map () 14.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {30} 30-es5.js, 30-es5.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {42} 42-es2015.js, 42-es2015.js.map () 20.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {42} 42-es5.js, 42-es5.js.map () 20.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {41} 41-es2015.js, 41-es2015.js.map () 37.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {41} 41-es5.js, 41-es5.js.map () 37.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {43} 43-es2015.js, 43-es2015.js.map () 19.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {43} 43-es5.js, 43-es5.js.map () 20.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {39} 39-es2015.js, 39-es2015.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {39} 39-es5.js, 39-es5.js.map () 15.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {36} 36-es2015.js, 36-es2015.js.map () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {36} 36-es5.js, 36-es5.js.map () 13.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {44} 44-es2015.js, 44-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {44} 44-es5.js, 44-es5.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {46} 46-es2015.js, 46-es2015.js.map () 12 kB  [rendered]
chunk {46} 46-es5.js, 46-es5.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {45} 45-es2015.js, 45-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {45} 45-es5.js, 45-es5.js.map () 13.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {48} 48-es2015.js, 48-es2015.js.map () 20.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {48} 48-es5.js, 48-es5.js.map () 21.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {40} 40-es2015.js, 40-es2015.js.map () 14.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {40} 40-es5.js, 40-es5.js.map () 15.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {53} 53-es2015.js, 53-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {53} 53-es5.js, 53-es5.js.map () 13 kB  [rendered]
chunk {47} 47-es2015.js, 47-es2015.js.map () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {47} 47-es5.js, 47-es5.js.map () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {51} 51-es2015.js, 51-es2015.js.map () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {51} 51-es5.js, 51-es5.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {55} 55-es2015.js, 55-es2015.js.map () 24.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {55} 55-es5.js, 55-es5.js.map () 24.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {52} 52-es2015.js, 52-es2015.js.map () 12.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {52} 52-es5.js, 52-es5.js.map () 13 kB  [rendered]
chunk {50} 50-es2015.js, 50-es2015.js.map () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {50} 50-es5.js, 50-es5.js.map () 19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {49} 49-es2015.js, 49-es2015.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {49} 49-es5.js, 49-es5.js.map () 22.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {58} 58-es2015.js, 58-es2015.js.map () 15.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {58} 58-es5.js, 58-es5.js.map () 16 kB  [rendered]
chunk {56} 56-es2015.js, 56-es2015.js.map () 26.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {56} 56-es5.js, 56-es5.js.map () 27 kB  [rendered]
chunk {54} 54-es2015.js, 54-es2015.js.map () 6.49 kB  [rendered]
chunk {54} 54-es5.js, 54-es5.js.map () 6.58 kB  [rendered]
chunk {57} 57-es2015.js, 57-es2015.js.map () 23.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {57} 57-es5.js, 57-es5.js.map () 24.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {59} 59-es2015.js, 59-es2015.js.map () 15.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {59} 59-es5.js, 59-es5.js.map () 15.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {63} 63-es2015.js, 63-es2015.js.map () 36.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {63} 63-es5.js, 63-es5.js.map () 36.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {62} 62-es2015.js, 62-es2015.js.map () 36.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {62} 62-es5.js, 62-es5.js.map () 36.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {64} 64-es2015.js, 64-es2015.js.map () 10.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {64} 64-es5.js, 64-es5.js.map () 11 kB  [rendered]
chunk {61} 61-es2015.js, 61-es2015.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {61} 61-es5.js, 61-es5.js.map () 22.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {66} 66-es2015.js, 66-es2015.js.map () 6.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {66} 66-es5.js, 66-es5.js.map () 7.15 kB  [rendered]
chunk {60} 60-es2015.js, 60-es2015.js.map () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {60} 60-es5.js, 60-es5.js.map () 22.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {69} 69-es2015.js, 69-es2015.js.map () 8.34 kB  [rendered]
chunk {69} 69-es5.js, 69-es5.js.map () 8.91 kB  [rendered]
chunk {65} 65-es2015.js, 65-es2015.js.map () 6.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {65} 65-es5.js, 65-es5.js.map () 7.16 kB  [rendered]
chunk {68} 68-es2015.js, 68-es2015.js.map () 14.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {68} 68-es5.js, 68-es5.js.map () 15 kB  [rendered]
chunk {67} 67-es2015.js, 67-es2015.js.map () 14.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {67} 67-es5.js, 67-es5.js.map () 14.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {73} 73-es2015.js, 73-es2015.js.map () 18.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {73} 73-es5.js, 73-es5.js.map () 18.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {70} 70-es2015.js, 70-es2015.js.map () 1.84 kB  [rendered]
chunk {70} 70-es5.js, 70-es5.js.map () 2.05 kB  [rendered]
chunk {72} 72-es2015.js, 72-es2015.js.map () 12.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {72} 72-es5.js, 72-es5.js.map () 12.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {74} 74-es2015.js, 74-es2015.js.map () 18.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {74} 74-es5.js, 74-es5.js.map () 19.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {75} 75-es2015.js, 75-es2015.js.map () 11 kB  [rendered]
chunk {75} 75-es5.js, 75-es5.js.map () 11.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {71} 71-es2015.js, 71-es2015.js.map () 12.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {71} 71-es5.js, 71-es5.js.map () 12.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {articles-articles-module} articles-articles-module-es2015.js, articles-articles-module-es2015.js.map (articles-articles-module) 10.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {articles-articles-module} articles-articles-module-es5.js, articles-articles-module-es5.js.map (articles-articles-module) 11 kB  [rendered]
chunk {77} 77-es2015.js, 77-es2015.js.map () 20.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {77} 77-es5.js, 77-es5.js.map () 20.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {76} 76-es2015.js, 76-es2015.js.map () 10.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {76} 76-es5.js, 76-es5.js.map () 11.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {appdashas-appdashas-module} appdashas-appdashas-module-es2015.js, appdashas-appdashas-module-es2015.js.map (appdashas-appdashas-module) 17.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {appdashas-appdashas-module} appdashas-appdashas-module-es5.js, appdashas-appdashas-module-es5.js.map (appdashas-appdashas-module) 18.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {chardasha-chardasha-module} chardasha-chardasha-module-es2015.js, chardasha-chardasha-module-es2015.js.map (chardasha-chardasha-module) 19 kB  [rendered]
chunk {chardasha-chardasha-module} chardasha-chardasha-module-es5.js, chardasha-chardasha-module-es5.js.map (chardasha-chardasha-module) 19.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {avchart-avchart-module} avchart-avchart-module-es2015.js, avchart-avchart-module-es2015.js.map (avchart-avchart-module) 11.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {avchart-avchart-module} avchart-avchart-module-es5.js, avchart-avchart-module-es5.js.map (avchart-avchart-module) 11.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {core-js-js} core-js-js-es2015.js, core-js-js-es2015.js.map (core-js-js) 78.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {core-js-js} core-js-js-es5.js, core-js-js-es5.js.map (core-js-js) 148 kB  [rendered]
chunk {basicinfo-basicinfo-module} basicinfo-basicinfo-module-es2015.js, basicinfo-basicinfo-module-es2015.js.map (basicinfo-basicinfo-module) 11.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {basicinfo-basicinfo-module} basicinfo-basicinfo-module-es5.js, basicinfo-basicinfo-module-es5.js.map (basicinfo-basicinfo-module) 11.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {appinfo-appinfo-module} appinfo-appinfo-module-es2015.js, appinfo-appinfo-module-es2015.js.map (appinfo-appinfo-module) 7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {appinfo-appinfo-module} appinfo-appinfo-module-es5.js, appinfo-appinfo-module-es5.js.map (appinfo-appinfo-module) 7.56 kB  [rendered]
chunk {common} common-es2015.js, common-es2015.js.map (common) 24.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {common} common-es5.js, common-es5.js.map (common) 25.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {catalogue-catalogue-module} catalogue-catalogue-module-es2015.js, catalogue-catalogue-module-es2015.js.map (catalogue-catalogue-module) 14.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {catalogue-catalogue-module} catalogue-catalogue-module-es5.js, catalogue-catalogue-module-es5.js.map (catalogue-catalogue-module) 15.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module} ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module-es2015.js, ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module-es2015.js.map (ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module) 9.22 kB  [rendered]
chunk {ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module} ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module-es5.js, ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module-es5.js.map (ashtakvarga-ashtakvarga-module) 9.83 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4} default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4-es2015.js, default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4-es2015.js.map (default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4) 15.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4} default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4-es5.js, default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4-es5.js.map (default~appdashas-appdashas-module~basicinfo-basicinfo-module~catalogue-catalogue-module~chardasha-c~a077b2d4) 14.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {charts-charts-module} charts-charts-module-es2015.js, charts-charts-module-es2015.js.map (charts-charts-module) 16.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {charts-charts-module} charts-charts-module-es5.js, charts-charts-module-es5.js.map (charts-charts-module) 17.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dashas-dashas-module} dashas-dashas-module-es2015.js, dashas-dashas-module-es2015.js.map (dashas-dashas-module) 10.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dashas-dashas-module} dashas-dashas-module-es5.js, dashas-dashas-module-es5.js.map (dashas-dashas-module) 10.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js} css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js-es2015.js, css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js-es2015.js.map (css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js) 21.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js} css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js-es5.js, css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js-es5.js.map (css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js) 22.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c} default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c-es2015.js, default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c-es2015.js.map (default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c) 23.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c} default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c-es5.js, default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c-es5.js.map (default~appdashas-appdashas-module~avchart-avchart-module~chardasha-chardasha-module~charts-charts-m~69a77f2c) 23 kB  [rendered]
chunk {focus-visible-70713a0c-js} focus-visible-70713a0c-js-es2015.js, focus-visible-70713a0c-js-es2015.js.map (focus-visible-70713a0c-js) 2.16 kB  [rendered]
chunk {focus-visible-70713a0c-js} focus-visible-70713a0c-js-es5.js, focus-visible-70713a0c-js-es5.js.map (focus-visible-70713a0c-js) 2.24 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js} dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js-es2015.js, dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js-es2015.js.map (dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js) 19.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js} dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js-es5.js, dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js-es5.js.map (dom-96781eef-a2fb04dd-js) 30.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {feedback-feedback-module} feedback-feedback-module-es2015.js, feedback-feedback-module-es2015.js.map (feedback-feedback-module) 11.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {feedback-feedback-module} feedback-feedback-module-es5.js, feedback-feedback-module-es5.js.map (feedback-feedback-module) 12.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {index-69c37885-js} index-69c37885-js-es2015.js, index-69c37885-js-es2015.js.map (index-69c37885-js) 37.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {index-69c37885-js} index-69c37885-js-es5.js, index-69c37885-js-es5.js.map (index-69c37885-js) 36.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dom-js} dom-js-es2015.js, dom-js-es2015.js.map (dom-js) 20.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {dom-js} dom-js-es5.js, dom-js-es5.js.map (dom-js) 30.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module-es2015.js, home-home-module-es2015.js.map (home-home-module) 16.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module-es5.js, home-home-module-es5.js.map (home-home-module) 17.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js} hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js-es2015.js, hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js-es2015.js.map (hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js) 2.07 kB  [rendered]
chunk {hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js} hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js-es5.js, hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js-es5.js.map (hardware-back-button-5afe3cb0-js) 2.17 kB  [rendered]
chunk {md-transition-fea2bbfb-js} md-transition-fea2bbfb-js-es2015.js, md-transition-fea2bbfb-js-es2015.js.map (md-transition-fea2bbfb-js) 3.92 kB  [rendered]
chunk {md-transition-fea2bbfb-js} md-transition-fea2bbfb-js-es5.js, md-transition-fea2bbfb-js-es5.js.map (md-transition-fea2bbfb-js) 3.98 kB  [rendered]
chunk {ios-transition-504cdd09-js} ios-transition-504cdd09-js-es2015.js, ios-transition-504cdd09-js-es2015.js.map (ios-transition-504cdd09-js) 26.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {ios-transition-504cdd09-js} ios-transition-504cdd09-js-es5.js, ios-transition-504cdd09-js-es5.js.map (ios-transition-504cdd09-js) 25.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {kundli-kundli-module} kundli-kundli-module-es2015.js, kundli-kundli-module-es2015.js.map (kundli-kundli-module) 13 kB  [rendered]
chunk {kundli-kundli-module} kundli-kundli-module-es5.js, kundli-kundli-module-es5.js.map (kundli-kundli-module) 13.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 54 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 57.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {input-shims-a4fc53ac-js} input-shims-a4fc53ac-js-es2015.js, input-shims-a4fc53ac-js-es2015.js.map (input-shims-a4fc53ac-js) 13.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {input-shims-a4fc53ac-js} input-shims-a4fc53ac-js-es5.js, input-shims-a4fc53ac-js-es5.js.map (input-shims-a4fc53ac-js) 13.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {notif-notif-module} notif-notif-module-es2015.js, notif-notif-module-es2015.js.map (notif-notif-module) 9.79 kB  [rendered]
chunk {notif-notif-module} notif-notif-module-es5.js, notif-notif-module-es5.js.map (notif-notif-module) 10.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js} shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js-es2015.js, shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js-es2015.js.map (shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js) 14.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js} shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js-es5.js, shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js-es5.js.map (shadow-css-4889ae62-23996f3f-js) 15.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {showarticle-showarticle-module} showarticle-showarticle-module-es2015.js, showarticle-showarticle-module-es2015.js.map (showarticle-showarticle-module) 8.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {showarticle-showarticle-module} showarticle-showarticle-module-es5.js, showarticle-showarticle-module-es5.js.map (showarticle-showarticle-module) 9.35 kB  [rendered]
chunk {navchardasha-navchardasha-module} navchardasha-navchardasha-module-es2015.js, navchardasha-navchardasha-module-es2015.js.map (navchardasha-navchardasha-module) 14.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {navchardasha-navchardasha-module} navchardasha-navchardasha-module-es5.js, navchardasha-navchardasha-module-es5.js.map (navchardasha-navchardasha-module) 15.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {pataki-pataki-module} pataki-pataki-module-es2015.js, pataki-pataki-module-es2015.js.map (pataki-pataki-module) 10.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {pataki-pataki-module} pataki-pataki-module-es5.js, pataki-pataki-module-es5.js.map (pataki-pataki-module) 10.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js} swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js-es2015.js, swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js-es2015.js.map (swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js) 176 kB  [rendered]
chunk {swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js} swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js-es5.js, swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js-es5.js.map (swiper-bundle-ccdaac54-js) 197 kB  [rendered]
chunk {preference-preference-module} preference-preference-module-es2015.js, preference-preference-module-es2015.js.map (preference-preference-module) 12.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {preference-preference-module} preference-preference-module-es5.js, preference-preference-module-es5.js.map (preference-preference-module) 13.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 4.94 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 5.24 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 115 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 117 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 11.2 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 11.2 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {swipe-back-35ad8e37-js} swipe-back-35ad8e37-js-es2015.js, swipe-back-35ad8e37-js-es2015.js.map (swipe-back-35ad8e37-js) 2.69 kB  [rendered]
chunk {swipe-back-35ad8e37-js} swipe-back-35ad8e37-js-es5.js, swipe-back-35ad8e37-js-es5.js.map (swipe-back-35ad8e37-js) 2.78 kB  [rendered]
chunk {tap-click-ca00ce7f-js} tap-click-ca00ce7f-js-es2015.js, tap-click-ca00ce7f-js-es2015.js.map (tap-click-ca00ce7f-js) 6.38 kB  [rendered]
chunk {tap-click-ca00ce7f-js} tap-click-ca00ce7f-js-es5.js, tap-click-ca00ce7f-js-es5.js.map (tap-click-ca00ce7f-js) 6.39 kB  [rendered]
chunk {status-tap-32c72c43-js} status-tap-32c72c43-js-es2015.js, status-tap-32c72c43-js-es2015.js.map (status-tap-32c72c43-js) 1.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {status-tap-32c72c43-js} status-tap-32c72c43-js-es5.js, status-tap-32c72c43-js-es5.js.map (status-tap-32c72c43-js) 1.89 kB  [rendered]
chunk {transit-transit-module} transit-transit-module-es2015.js, transit-transit-module-es2015.js.map (transit-transit-module) 15.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {transit-transit-module} transit-transit-module-es5.js, transit-transit-module-es5.js.map (transit-transit-module) 16.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {cordova} cordova.js, cordova.js.map (cordova) 63.5 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-11T18:39:16.403Z - Hash: 9fd3a7fd7ba4a52b6030 - Time: 39684ms
```

[See the command prompt from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbyId.png)

I am using Windows 10.

Can someone suggest me how to fix this issue.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Have you all the requirements in place? meaning android sdk and java8 and gradle?

Comment: Yes, I could build this previously.

Comment: I hope you have not changed branches while in the process

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Just added a cordova plugin admob. I just tried by removing it. It still stukcs.

Comment: Try `ionic cordova run android --verbose` and update the output for us please.

Comment: @rzp Updated. Please check.

Comment: I also faced some kind of issue on windows machine. I suggest to rebuild it and wait it will be get done automatically.

Comment: How long did it take to build? @NehaShah

Comment: It is not that much maximum might be 6-7 minutes and do not push terminal on background.

Comment: Well, I tried. Left it for more than 1 hour. Nothing happend. @NehaShah

Answer (score 0):

This was an antivirus problem. It was an unwanted antivirus program that came in a software bundle that was blocking the path. After I uninstalled the antivirus, it's working fine now.